# Is there a bijective function $f: \Bbb Z \to \Bbb N$ that involves only elementary arithmetic and no piecewise functions?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, integers, natural-numbers

As the title suggests, I'm looking for a function $f : \Bbb Z \to \Bbb N$ that satisfies the following:

$$
\forall y \in \Bbb N, \exists! x \in \Bbb Z : y = f(x)
\\
\therefore\quad
\Bbb N = \left\{ f(x) \mid x \in \Bbb Z \right\}
\quad\land\quad
\Bbb Z = \left\{ f^{-1}(y) \mid y \in \Bbb N \right\}
$$

The most common bijective function I've found is something similar to this:

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
2x+1 & x \geq 0
\\
-2x & x \lt 0
\end{cases}
\\
\therefore\quad
f^{-1}(y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{y-1} 2 & \text{$y$ is odd}
\\
-\frac y 2 & \text{$y$ is even}
\end{cases}
$$

However, this definition is obviously a piecewise function. Is there any way to write a bijective function that:

- Doesn't use a piecewise function (is the same formula for all of the domain $\Bbb Z$)
- Doesn't use any non-elementary functions like $\sin(x)$, $\lvert x \rvert$, etc.
- Only uses addition/subtraction, multiplication/division, and exponentiation/roots/logs

?

Comment: I kind of wonder by what means logarithms should be elementary while trigonometric functions shouldn't.

Comment: @Gae.S. Logarithms are absolutely elementary functions. First, $x=y+z \implies y=x-z \implies z=x-y$. Next, $x=y \cdot z \implies y=\frac x z \implies z = \frac x y$. Finally, $x=y^z \implies y=\sqrt[z] x \implies z = \log_y x$.

Comment: So I guess in your world Bring's radical is elementary.

Answer (score 2):

The OP ruled out the function $|x|$.  But another answer uses $\sqrt{x^2}$.  So, assuming that $|x|$ is OK, we can use this
$$
f(x) := 2\left|x-\frac{1}{4}\right|-\frac{1}{2}
$$
Then $f$ maps $0$ to $0$, maps the negative integers to the positive even integers, and maps the positive integers to the positive odd integers.

Comment: $\sqrt{x^2}=\{x,-x\}$, not $\lvert x \rvert$. You’re assuming that you may restrict the range of the root function to that of the principal root, which unfortunately is not an acceptable operation in the function Im looking for.